# DATEDIFF with a number instead of a date

Tags: sql, sql-server, datediff, dateadd

I am having some trouble trying to understand how DATEDIFF should work. I saw in some cases an int argument instead of a valid date like the examples bellow:

```
/* Output is 119 */
SELECT DATEDIFF(year, 6, '2019/05/15');

/* Output is 6.227 */
SELECT DATEDIFF(week, 6, '2019/05/15');
```

In this case how number 6 is being treated? What does it mean?

Thanks!

Comment: It's cast to a `datetime` implicitly

Comment: I dare say if someone is using that, they're not using it right at all. The docs clearly state that the second parameter is the *startdate* and lists all date-types as valid arguments. None of which are int.

Comment: This unfortunate implicit conversion is the reason one should use `datetime2` instead of `datetime`

Comment: I'd be far more concerned about using that date format instead of one that won't be affected by language settings. Using integers and direct math is a great advantage of the old date types, for some of us.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an example of [implict data type conversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-conversion-database-engine?view=sql-server-2017). [DATEDIFF()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datediff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) allows `datetime` as a parameter type, so `6` is converted implicitly to `datetime` and `DATEADD()` converts `0` to `1900-01-01`.

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(year, 6, '2019/05/15');
SELECT DATEDIFF(week, 6, '2019/05/15');
```

is actually

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(year, DATEADD(day, 0, 6), '2019/05/15');
SELECT DATEDIFF(week, DATEADD(day, 0, 6), '2019/05/15');
```

Comment: ...and then you still have an implicit conversion in the `DATEADD`, so maybe rewrite that as what `0` becomes too -- `1900-01-01`.

Comment: While this is all correct I have an issue with "DATEDIFF allows datetime as a parameter type, so 6 is converted implicitly to datetime." DATEDIFF also allows DATE, DATETIMEOFFSET, DATETIME2, SMALLDATETIME, TIME. So why isn't it implicitly converted to one of those? Is it converted to whatever doesn't give an error?

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thanks for this note, I've updated the answer.

Comment: @HoneyBadger Data  types `date`, '`time', 'datetime2' do not allow conversion from integer, so `datetime` seems to be the only possible candidate for implicit conversion.

Comment: @HoneyBadger: if you really want to know, might make it a separate question. As is usual in T-SQL, `DATEDIFF` appears to follow its own rules here. (For example, while conversion between `INT` and `DATETIME2` is not permitted, `DATEDIFF(DAY, SYSDATETIME(), 0)` *is* permitted, so it's not a simple matter of following the implicit conversion/precedence rules.)

Comment: Thank you very much @Zhorov, perfect answer!

Answer (score 1):

If only a time value is assigned to a date data type variable, DATEDIFF sets the value of the missing date part to the default value: 1900-01-01.
So, the following snippet returns 119 ( 6 = 7th January 1990 )

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(year, '1900/01/07', '2019/05/15');
```

Comment: Your first sentence is correct but irrelevant, because `6` is not a time value at all. The internal representation of `DATETIME` uses the fractional part to represent times. The original statement is equivalent to `DATEDIFF(year, '1900-01-07', '2019-05-15')` (which, of course, also yields 119).